# WSO2: How can I use iterate mediator for a json array and then log each element?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have this json file:

```
{
   "data":{
      "call_location":[
         {
            "id": 1,
            "ycoordinate":44.4176067
         },
         {
            "id": 2,
            "ycoordinate":46.6680591712414
            
         },
         {
            "id": 3,
            "ycoordinate":45.4176067
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And I want to have each element into a property and log the property like this:

```
<iterate id="jsonIterator" expression="json-eval($.data.call_location)">
            <target>
                <sequence>
                    <propertyGroup>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.id)" name="id" scope="default" type="NUMBER"/>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.ycoordinate)" name="ycoordinate" scope="default" type="NUMBER"/>
                    </propertyGroup>
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:id" name="log_id :"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ycoordinate" name="log_ycoordinate :"/>
                    </log> 
                </sequence>
            </target>
</iterate>
```

When I'm sending a request through postman it's only trying to send the request endlessly ("Sending request..." message)
What am I doing wrong? Thank you
*I want to use iterate mediator not foreach

Comment: Hi EAGame, the iterate mediator is a bit of a funny one. Can you add what you share in the log output? This might tell us a bit more of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Change in the `propertyGroup` the properties types from `type="NUMBER"` to `type="STRING"`. Propably WSO2 throws error when trying to convert into the specified type, using json-eval() function.